# How to append data to buffer in shell script?

Tags: shell, cat, buffer

I'd like to do following using shell script: (for simplicity, I use same data for INPUT. In real case, the data changes with loop label jj)

```
#!/bin/sh
for jj in `seq 100`; do
    cat INPUT.file >> OUTPUT.file
done
```

However, this is very inefficient since opening and closing the file are in the loop. When the size of the INPUT.file is large, this code will be very slow. So I am wondering if there is a way to have/create a buffer like create a pre-allocated variable in C.

Comment: I found out I can do "Creating a ram disk on Linux" (http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux). Unfortunately, I don't have the root privilege. Is this the only way that can speed up this operation?

Comment: You still haven't said what you intend to achieve with this.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. What I intended to do is essentially inserting different data into different places (~4000 places) of a large file. I use shell with sed/awk. I use loop to generate the data and insert them to the large file. So the code above is what I came with and it is not efficient.

Comment: You do realise this loop runs only twice?

Comment: `for k in blah foo; do cat "$k" >> bar; done` (or the prefix one) -> `cat blah foo >> bar`. Cat is used to Concatenate FILE(s).

Comment: Actually the loop runs 100 times since `seq 100` generates numbers from 1 to 100. (grave accent (`) performs a command substitution).

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)'s answer to ["Why there is such a difference in execution time of echo and cat?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230206/why-there-is-such-a-difference-in-exection-time-of-echo-and-cat/230230#230230), the answer of [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) may be a little improved by calling `cat` only once (however, this "a little" amount may become a lot for big data and numerous loop iterations; on my system, this script takes ~75% time the loop-having script takes):

```
#!/bin/sh
yes INPUT.file | head -100 | xargs cat >> OUTPUT.file
```

Comment: Did you _really_ mean **.75%**?  Or **75%**?  The latter seems more likely...

Comment: @TobySpeight: It was a funny mistake...thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

Consider redirecting the loop itself:

```
#!/bin/sh
for jj in seq 100; do
    cat INPUT.file
done >> OUTPUT.file
```

Comment: This is better. > or >>? Is there a better way since this one still opens and closes the INPUT.file.

Comment: @XiaopengHuang Depends on what you want to achieve. How big is `INPUT`?

Comment: It can be ~50MB, but normally it is ~5MB.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is your main concern, then you may find that `cat` isn't fast enough at this task.  You may want to write the constituent files to the output in parallel.

I knocked up a quick version of a parallel `cat` with the following caveats:

1. all the input files must be regular files (so we know the size in advance).
2. do not write or truncate the input files while `fcat` is running
3. the output file musn't already exist (to prevent accidents, and also to avoid wasting time reading what we're about to overwrite).

Obviously, this is a quick proof-of-concept, so could be made more robust, but here's the idea:

fcat.c:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


struct in_fd {
    int fd;
    int err;
    off_t start;
    struct stat s;
};

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    char *outfile = argv[--argc];

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s INFILE... OUTFILE\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct in_fd *infiles = calloc(argc, sizeof *infiles);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        struct in_fd *const input = infiles + i;
        char const *const filename = argv[i];
        input->err = 0;
        if ((input->fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
            perror(filename);
            input->err = errno;
            continue;
        }
        if (fstat(input->fd, &input->s)) {
            perror(filename);
            input->err = errno;
            continue;
        }
        if (!S_ISREG(input->s.st_mode)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: not a regular file\n", filename);
            input->err = EINVAL;
            continue;
        }
    }

    off_t total = 0;
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        if (infiles[i].err)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        infiles[i].start = total;
        total += infiles[i].s.st_size;
    }

    int out_fd = open(outfile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
    if (out_fd < 1) {
        perror(outfile);
        return 1;
    }

    if (ftruncate(out_fd, total)) {
        perror(outfile);
        return 1;
    }

    /* On Linux, you might wish to add MAP_HUGETLB */
    char *out_mem = mmap(NULL, total, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, out_fd, 0);
    if (out_mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror(outfile);
        return 1;
    }

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        struct in_fd *const input = infiles + i;
        char *p = out_mem + input->start;
        char *end = p + input->s.st_size;
        input->err = 0;
        while (p < end) {
            int r = read(input->fd, p, end-p);
            if (r < 0) {
                if (errno != EINTR) {
                    perror(argv[i]);
                    input->err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                p += r;
            }
        }
        close(infiles->fd);
    }


    if (munmap(out_mem, total)) {
        perror(outfile);
    }

    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        if (infiles[i].err) {
            unlink(outfile);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra
CFLAGS += -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE
CFLAGS += -g -O2
CFLAGS += -fopenmp

all: fcat
.PHONY:all
```

My timing results with 12 threads show elapsed times of 0.2 seconds compared with 2.3 seconds for `cat` (median of three runs each, with hot cache, on 48 files totalling 138M).